# Displaying image in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe, imageicon

I have a JFrame and I want to load a image to it when I click the load image button. Once I click next button I want to change the image. Loading image to a variable is no problem. I load it to `Image img`. I just want to show it. Which means i want to load it to a JLable or JPanel. How can I do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let use [ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) & [JLabel.setIcon(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29)

Comment: An `Image` is just an image... It's graphical data. How you obtained it or whether the data was decoded from a jpeg, png, bmp or whatever format should not matter.

Comment: I used ImageIcon but it only shows part of the image. Not entire image.

Comment: Resize the image to the size of the container.
[Image.getScaledInstance(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

[JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) supports [Icon/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)s.  This means that you can create a simple JLabel, pass an ImageIcon to it, and have it display.  This should probably cover what you need.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Comment: I am using NetBeans IDE so i cant accsess the constructor. Any other methods? And it wont load jpgs.

Comment: I don't really understand what NetBeans has to do with this, but it certainly does work with JPG. http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/45imageicon.html

Comment: I used image icon but it only shows some part of the image. Not entire image.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom component and override the `paint(Graphics g)` method. Use the given `Graphics` object to paint the image. You could cast to `Graphics2D` first if you need some more advanced options. Look through the methods defined by `Graphics(2D)`, you'll find what you need pretty soon.

A subclass of `JPanel` would work well. The best choice really kind of depends on how you managed the contents of the JFrame.

Comment: How could i do this in NetBeans?

Comment: Are you writing a NetBeans plugin module, or just a Java app? In the latter case, the IDE doesn't matter. But I suppose you ask because you might be creating a GUI using the builder supplied by NetBeans. Even if you do that, you'll still have to do some programming of certain components yourself. I don't know if NetBeans has some pre-baked image display component.